# Poset axioms of Boolean algebra

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, ac.commutative-algebra

I found in Awodey's "Theory Category", second edition p34, a set of poset axioms to define Boolean algebras, whereas I don't see how they can be sufficient.

Here are the axioms:

> A Boolean algebra is a poset B
>   equipped with distinguished elements
>   0, 1, binary operations $a \vee b$ of
>   "join" and $a \wedge b$ of "meet", and
>   a unary operation $\neg b$ of
>   "complementation". These are required
>   to satisfy the conditions $$0 \le a$$
>   $$a \le 1$$ $$a \le c \text{ and } b
> > \le c \text{ iff } a\vee b \le c $$
>   $$c \le a \text{ and } c \le b \text{
> > iff } c \le a \wedge b$$ $$a \le \neg
> > b \text{ iff } a \wedge b = 0$$
>   $$\neg\neg a =a$$

I can see that from these axioms I can deduce several of the common properties of boolean algebras, so for example I can prove $\forall c, c\wedge\neg c =0$, $\forall (a,c), a\wedge c \le c$, etc. but there are some properties I cannot see how they are provable in this axiomatics.

Here one of which I tried so hard (and failed) to prove from the axioms above: $\forall (a,b), a \le a \vee b$

Could somebody guide me? I am trying to make something impossible? Is my mistake on things I think that are required to be true in a Boolean algebra and are not?

Comment: In your second-last axiom, you probably want to say $a\wedge b=0$ rather than $a\vee b=0$. 

Comment: Yes, thank you. Corrected. I confused three times "vee" and "wedge" while redacting... I hope all is corrected now.

Comment: The claim that $a\leq a\vee b$ seems to follow immediately from the third axiom, by taking $c=a\vee b$, since $c\leq c$.

Comment: Exact. Now I feel so stupid that I'd like to close my question...
Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey, don't worry about it! We all miss easy things sometimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As remarked by Joel, this is indeed very direct starting from $a\vee b \le a \vee b$ and using the third axiom. Many thanks to have unstucked me.